# He said false sentence

Tags: word-usage

I have a sentence which is "He said false sentence". 
Does this sentence Sound NATURAL? How can I create the most natural version of it using the words in the quotation marks? 
Ps: It meant to say his sentence was not correct.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sentence* is a countable noun, so requires an article in the singular. It is usually used only when we are talking about the language - the specific words and grammar - not about the meaning.

*Say* usually takes as object either a *that* clause, or a direct quotation, or *something* (usually followed by a qualification or relative clause). Examples:

> He said that he was not coming.
>
> He said "That's wrong".
>
> He said something [that] I didn't understand.

Following it with another kind of noun phrase (as "a false sentence") is not idiomatic.

You probably want:

> He said something false.

or

> He made a false statement.